# LESS mixin as mixin variable

Tags: css, less, mixins

I'm trying to deal with web fonts generated by font squirrel with LESS. The problem is that for each font-weight, font-squirrel generated a separate font-face: myfont-regular, myfont-medium etc.

So I was trying to create a mixin which does font declaration and pass it as concatenated string of font-name ("apercu_") and weight('light', 'regular', 'bold') as font parameter:

```
.font(
    @weight: 'light',
    .textFont (@weight): {
        @family:~"apercu_@{weight}";
    },
    @size: 1.0em, 
    @lineheight: 1.4em, 
    @weight: normal, 
    @style: normal, @variant: normal) {
        font: @style @variant @weight @size~"/"@lineheight @family; 
    }
```

Calling it as:

```
body {
    .font('bold', .textFont('bold'), 1.1em, 1.4em, 300);
     background: @bg;
}
```

So that `.textFont('bold')` returns "apercu_bold" into the `.font` mixin. But I get :

> LESS.app Syntax error: that ')' is expected on line    .textFont
>   (@weight): {

Anyone has any ideas or maybe someone has already tries that ?
Thanks.

Comment: Well, it is not possible directly (mixins are not functions so they cannot *return* value). There's however four or five methods to do that indirectly. But before counting all those tricks, I actually wonder why you need a mixin for the font-family value, for example would not this be more easy to achieve the same [like this](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/11287940#file-23291468-1-less) or in similar fashion?

Comment: What's weird thought, but it's probably another question... For my site I use bookblock plugin for "page-turning". In my less I have two top-level page class .page1 et .page2 which serve as color/font themes: .page1 { .content {} …} etc. And when turning pages (alternating between calsses .page1 and .page2) of my site, first the "default" styles appears and only after a certain delay the colours and font are applied ? What the problem might be? If do not use nested classes in less, all works well.

Comment: I was also wondering how switch between `@family: "@{name}_@{nameWeight}";`and `@family: "@{name}";` depending on variable @static or @dynamic? Knowing that LESS does not support IF/ELSE, but has "guard" statements?

Comment: Just read the corresponding sections at the docs: [Pattern Matching](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-feature-pattern-matching), [Mixin Guards](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixin-guards-feature) etc. Depends on what you mean with `@static` and `@dynamic` (all Less variables are equal in that sense).

Comment: What I want to achieve is based on a variable that indicates wheather the font type is static or dynamic, meaning if its name is just a @name or if it's a dynamic name with font weight as suffix ?

Comment: It depends on the particular condition you're going to use to determine if the font is a "squirrel" one (font name? lack/presence of suffix variable? something else?)

Comment: I thought about the presence or absence of variable @sqeuirrel in `.font (... ` declaration, so that inside `  @family: "@{name}_@{nameWeight}";` or `  @family: "@{name}"; `? not sure how to do it? should i create two mixins?

Comment: `.font_dynamic(
    @name:       apercu,
    @nameWeight: light,
    @size:       1.0em,
    @lineHeight: 1.4em, 
    @weight:     normal,
    @style:      normal, 
    @variant:    normal) {
        @family: "@{name}_@{nameWeight}";
        font: @style @variant @weight @size~"/"@lineHeight @family, 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif; 
}`

Comment: `.font_static(
    @name:       apercu,
    @size:       1.0em,
    @lineHeight: 1.4em, 
    @weight:     normal,
    @style:      normal, 
    @variant:    normal) {
        @family: "@{name}";
        font: @style @variant @weight @size~"/"@lineHeight @family, 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif; 
}`

Comment: These are two mixins which differs only by `@family: "@{name}_@{nameWeight}"`or `@family: "@{name}"`. So is there a way to do that not by creating two separate mixins but one mixin and sort of conditional statement?